# Excel help: Check if a note is available for a list of jobs

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
Job No     Note Availability
123        Yes
123        No
124        No
124        No
125        Yes
```

In this case, the job 124 has no note while the job 123 and 125 have their notes. The job number can be repeated and if there is a note for at least 1 line, we consider it as the job has a note. So the result I want should show 2 Yes and 1 No.

Please help :) Thank you!

Comment: Are you expecting a Third Column to return your Yes or No Status as per your criteria? Input would be Job No & Notes Availability Columns, if so IF coupled with COUNTIFS function should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `COUNTIFS()`.  Say you want to know if Job `125` has a note.  Put `125` in say cell `C2`.  In `D2`, you can use:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$C$2,$B$2:$B$10,"Yes")
```

If it's greater than `0`, then there's a note for that Job No.

Edit: Or, for completeness: `=IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A6,C2,B2:B6,"Yes"),"Yes","No")`